Missing term in multipole moments for long wavelength limit - Jackson Chapter 16
In Jackson's Classical Electrodynamics (1st edition), Jackson writes an expression for the electric multipole moments in the long wavelength limit in equation (16.93), (16.94):
$$a_E(l, m) = \frac{4\pi k^{l+2}}{i(2l+1)!!}\left(\frac{l+1}{l}\right)^{1/2}\left(Q_{lm} + Q_{lm}'\right)\tag{16.93}$$
$$Q_{lm} = \int r^l Y_{lm}^\ast\rho\,d^3x \tag{16.94}$$
$$Q_{lm}' = \frac{-ik}{l+1}\int r^l Y_{lm}^\ast\nabla\cdot\left(\mathbf{r}\times\mathbf{\mathscr{M}}\right)\,d^3x\tag{16.94'}$$
Prior to this, he derives an exact expression for $a_E(l,m)$ in equation (16.91):
$$a_E(l, m) = \frac{4\pi k^2}{i\sqrt{l(l+1)}}\int Y_{lm}^\ast\left\{\rho\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left[rj_l(kr)\right] + \frac{ik}{c}\left(\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{J}\right)j_l(kr) - ik\nabla\cdot\left(\mathbf{r}\times\mathbf{\mathscr{M}}\right)j_l(kr)\right\}\,d^3x\tag{16.91}$$
In the limit where $kr \ll 1$ we have $j_l(kr) \sim \frac{(kr)^l}{(2l+1)!!}$ and after some work I can get the following approximation
$$a_E(l, m) \sim \frac{4\pi k^{l+2}}{i(2l+1)!!}\left(\frac{l+1}{l}\right)^{1/2}\left(Q_{lm} + Q_{lm}''\right)$$
where $Q_{lm}$ is as above, and
$$Q_{lm}'' = \frac{-ik}{l+1}\int r^l Y_{lm}^\ast\left[\nabla\cdot\left(\mathbf{r}\times\mathbf{\mathscr{M}}\right) - \frac{1}{c}\left(\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{J}\right)\right]\,d^3x$$
This is close to Jackson's result, except for the additional $-\frac{1}{c}\left(\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{J}\right)$ term.
This term comes directly from the corresponding $\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{J}$ term in (16.91) and I see no reason to neglect it since its order of magnitude appears the same as that of $\nabla\cdot\left(\mathbf{r}\times\mathbf{\mathscr{M}}\right)$ (both are $O(kr)$ smaller than the $\rho$ term).
There is a similar issue with a term missing in the long-wavelength limit for $a_M(l, m)$.
I'm not sure what mistake I am making or what assumption Jackson has that justifies neglecting this term.

maybe (?) because $\nabla (\mathbf r \times \mathbf M)=\mathbf M \cdot (\nabla \times \mathbf r) - \mathbf r \cdot (\nabla \times \mathbf M) = - \mathbf r \cdot (\nabla \times \mathbf M) $ and $c|\nabla \times \mathbf M| \gg |\mathbf J|$

That would be valid, I suppose, but nothing has been said about $\mathbf{J}$ or $\mathbf{\mathscr{M}}$ so far. And these are Gaussian units so I don't have a good intuition about what $\mathbf{M}$ and $\mathbf{J}/c$ are typically like.

these equations are also in Jackson 3rd edition on page 441, Eq (9.170) using SI units in which there is no $c$, but otherwise they are the same, in other words "magnetic current" vs. "electric charge current" (assuming your calculations are correct).

Right, so in SI units we'd be comparing $\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{J}$ and $\mathbf{r}\cdot\nabla\times\mathbf{M}$. Presumably the first has lower order of magnitude than the second, but I can't see why.
